# Only Professor X goes bald due to his psychic powers, why?

Tags: marvel, x-men

As per the Wikipedia page [says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Professor_X)

> With help from his powers and his natural genius, Xavier becomes an excellent student and athlete, though he gives up the latter, believing his powers give him an unfair advantage. Due to his powers, by the time he graduates from high school, Charles loses all of his hair.

Then why don't other psychic mutant lose their hair, for example: Emma Frost, Jean Grey, and [Legion (Son of Professor X)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legion_%28Marvel_Comics%29)? Why did it happen to only Professor X?

Comment: @onewho thanx for correction.

Comment: When you go bald early, you give all kinds of excuses...

Comment: For 3 years in the 1980s, he had a combover. I think Wilerson is right.

Comment: Knowing how much stress he puts on himself, one would assume it has nothing to do with his powers. BTW Was wikipedia sourced?

Comment: It's probably getting burned off by all the energy passing through the Cerebro helmet.  Probably causing him to get brain tumors too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Charles Xavier likely had a genetic predisposition for baldness, which was only accelerated by the activation of his mutant powers. It is a side effect of his mutant powers, not a trait associated with vast psionic ability in all mutants.**

[image: Cassandra Nova]

*Cassandra Nova, genetic twin to Charles Xavier, but actually an alien invader seeking powerful genetic material to copy.*

- When the Mummudrai, Cassandra Nova copied Charles' DNA in the womb, she too would eventually lose her hair, the same way Charles did, bolstering the idea that Xavier's powers were linked to eventual, premature hair loss.
- Cassandra Nova is Professor X's lost twin who died in the womb and is responsible for the 16 million mutants that were slaughtered in Genosha. She possesses similar telepathic powers as Charles Xavier and several latent abilities as well.
- Cassandra Nova can also induce mutants to undergo secondary mutations, with varying results. Emma Frost's secondary mutation offered her a diamond-like conversion of her physical form.

> The Mummudrai are noncorporeal parasites, composed solely of emotional energy born from the astral plane of existence. The first and most notable member of the mummudrai species to appear on panel is Cassandra Nova.